# ms access input mask MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: ms-access

Hi Im working in the UK creating a MS Access application. I have a textfield which will take in the date of something based on this format: MM/DD/YYYY.

However as I'm in the UK it uses the Short Date format of DD/MM/YYYY. How do I ensure it uses MM/DD/YYYY? Will it do this automatically if the application is opened in the states? Or do I have to provide an Input Mask and some VB code to sort it?

Thanks

Comment: You can find tons of information about this if you do an Internet search for "msaccess localization" or "msaccess internationalization."   MSAccess uses Control Panel/Regional Settings to determine how dates are displayed and interpreted, but always expects American format in literals, as in #MM/DD/YYYY#.  See also http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it - if you create a textfield and then change its format to MM/DD/YYYY - this will change whatever you enter into the American format - so for example you entered the UK format (DD/MM/YYYY) as 12/03/2012 this would change to 3/12/2012.

This solved my problem but others may arise if you wished to compare two date values or something. Hope this helps...